# How to force a Dell Latitude D830 to remain "on" after closing the lid?

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-12.04, suspend, lid

I'm repurposing and old `Dell Latitude D830` laptop for a `Nagios` monitoring server at work.  Works great until I close the lid.

Is there a way I can force this laptop not to suspend when I close the lid?  I have already changed the settings in Ubuntu to do nothing when I close the lid, and this works if I keep a user logged into the laptop.

But if I want to run a headerless server and have people login via SSH and I close the lid it immediately suspends.

Any secrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have installed Ubuntu, you will have the default power saving settings enabled.

This might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157629/how-to-prevent-computer-from-automatically-sleeping-and-or-hibernating